# Prove $\sigma^2(aX+b)=a^2\sigma^2(X)$ for discrete random variable

Tags: random-variable, descriptive-statistics, proof

I'm a total newbie to statistics/math in general, so please bare with me.

I'm currently reading the book [The Cartoon Guide to Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062731025), and stumbled upon the following statement (p. 69):

$$
\sigma^2(aX+b)=a^2\sigma^2(X)
$$

Is there a way to prove the truth of this statement? I've tried myself, but can't figure out what to do with the $b$ to make it "go away".

My attempt:

\begin{align}
\sigma^2(aX+b) &= \sum{(ax+b-\mu)^2p(x)}  \\
               &= a^2\sum{(x+b-\mu)^2p(x)}  \\
               &= a^2\sum{(x-\mu)^2p(x)}+\sum{b^2p(x)}  \\
               &= a^2\sigma^2(X)+\sum{b^2p(x)}
\end{align}

Comment: Your attempt is incorrect.  Recall $var(aX+b)=E[(aX+b-E[ax+b])^2]=E[(aX+b-aE[X]-b)^2]=E[(aX-E[aX])^2]=\sum a^2(X-E[X])^2p(x)$.  See the Wikipedia entry for variance for more info that will probably help

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld, Ah - I see. Could you please make it an answer, so that I can accept it? - Thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry.  I am too lazy right now...you understand so that is what matters :)

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld, Hehe :) - Looking at it, I can't stop wondering how come you get $E[aX+b] = aE[X]-b$ - but the book says that $E[aX+b] = aE[X]+b$.

Comment: $E[aX+b]=\sum (ax+b)p(x)$...then multiply everything out and remember the law of total probability.

Comment: Zachary didn't get $E[aX+b] = aE[X]-b$. He had $E[aX+b] = aE[X]+b$, which means that $-E[aX+b] = -aE[X]-b$.

Comment: Recall the definition the variance of a random variable X is $Var(X) = E(X^2)-E(X)^2$, so $Var(X)$ is just a function of $X$.  Using this, try substituting the value of $aX+b$ into the function (i.e. $Var(aX+b)$ and carrying out the algebra to expand terms and then simply. Pay attention to whether squared terms appear inside or outside of expectation (e.g. $E(X^2)$ vs. $E(X)^2$ -- These are two different terms.